# Reading output of wmic command into a single array and processing the array in Perl

Tags: windows, perl

My requirement as follows:

I am reading the output of the wmic command as follows:

```
my @pnames = `wmic product where "Name like '%Provider%'" get IdentifyingNumber, Name,Version`;

print "@pnames";
```

**Till here the output is as follows:**

```
IdentifyingNumber                        Name                                     Version

{E094B8EA-87B7-48DE-A0A8-A18AC8BFCDF4} .NET Data Provider for Teradata 14.00.0.0  14.00.0.0

{1551F9D6-1B14-4AE1-BABA-70A4319C236A}  ODBC Driver Provider                       14.00.0.0
```

**Processing the array**

```
foreach $name ( @pnames )
{
  chomp($name);

  #@names = split('need to pass something',$name); 
  # I want to split every input entry   into 3 parts- IdentifyingNumber, Name,Version similarly the way they read.

  $name =~ s/^\s+//; #remove leading spaces
  $name =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces

  # here logic goes this way, If the version number has matched, search for name and if name has matched display its identifying number 

  print "Identifying number(say $id) of the packge with name(say $pkg)\n";
}
```

Comment: hey thanks Zaid...Actually I want to put it that way...thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split by matching your input line

```
foreach my $line (@pnames) {
    my($id, $name, $version) = ($line =~ m/^\s*({.+?})\s+(.+?)\s+([\d.]+)\s*$/);
    ...
}
```

This captures the three parts `(...)` and assigns them to the variables `$id`, `$name` and `$version`.

Comment: `(.+)\s+` is equivalent to `(.+)\s`.

Comment: @melpomene This depends, if you want any trailing white space or not.

Comment: It does not depend. It is equivalent.